# Permission denied when i try to execute a python script from bash?

Tags: python, bash, shell, python-2.7

I downloaded a python script from the web and when i try to execute it from bash it throws a exception:

`User:python_script user$ ./python_script.py -n some_parameter -b`

The output is the following:

```
-bash: ./python_script.py: Permission denied
```

the file all ready has: `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of the script. How can i solve this?

Comment: Try having the shebang as `#!/usr/bin/env python` and feed back.

Comment: Do an ls -l see who owns the file. You might need to do a chown

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add execute permissions like so:

```
chmod u+x python_script.py
```

This assumes that the script is owned by you. If it isn't, you might need to change the group/other execute permissions or `chown` the file as appropriate.